# Compiler error plus code

Tags: java, windows, compiler-errors

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/game/player/Player.java
echo compiled Player folder

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" -javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/Launcher.java
echo compiled Server folder

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/game/player/dialogues/*.java
echo compiling Dialogues

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/*.java
echo compiled Main Server Folder

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/game/player/content/*.java
echo compiled Main Server Folder

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" javac -Xlint:unchecked/*; -sourcepath src src/com/rs/net/decoders/handlers/*.java
echo Compiled all Successfully
pause
```

I am trying to fix my compiler but nothing is working what should i do? These are the codes i have in it. Here is what happens when i run it.

```
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked/*;
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiled Player folder
javac: invalid flag: -javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiled Server folder
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked/*;
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiling Dialogues
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked/*;
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiled Main Server Folder
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked/*;
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiled Main Server Folder
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:unchecked/*;
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Compiled all Successfully
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the "-Xlint:unchecked/*;" everywhere.
Also, it doesn't make sense to me to have the explicit 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javac.exe" followed by "javac".
Compiling should just work with lines like:

```
javac src/com/rs/game/player/Player.java
```

etc. unless you PATH isn't set properly.